# How to convert InputStream to Image in JSP and display the image in another JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I'm doing a photo album with jsp. I have stream of image from AmazonS3, How can I convert the InputStream to Image file in jsp

Comment: Add the code you've tried.

Comment: S3Object s3object = conn.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket.getName(), objectSummary.getKey()));
InputStream input = s3object.getObjectContent();

With this i got my inputstream, I dont know how to convert this to image

Comment: add code to your question not comments.

Comment: did you find the solution?